# Cant connect to new Amazon AWS Centos instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I cannot connect to my AWS instance. I've searched the other related topics, they've not given me the answer.

I have created a Centos AMI and gone through all the steps. At the end I have imported a key pair.

The instance is created and everything seems fine. Except that I cannot connect to the server.

VIA PUTTY
Putty says: Login As, followed by password request, which of course I don't have. I dont know how to connect using a PEM file there does not seem to be a way to connect using PEM file.

VIA BITVISE
Ive created the keypair in Bitvise. When I connect Ive tried username ec2-user and root and asked for the initial_method to be publickey+slot2+password (and without password).

It ALWAYS asks me for a password, And when I enter (or not) the passphrase I created with the key it fails EVERYTIME to connect.

Driving me crazy, WTH Amazon! Just create a user/ password for us to connect with!!! This key pair thing is just crazy.

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Sounds like you're just starting off with AWS. Amazon itself doesn't provide CentOS images (they have Amazon Linux instead, which is built on CentOS, so well worth a look!). Hence, you might want to try out official images before using community images to guarantee that the error is not somewhere outside of your control. If, as you suggest, you actually created an AMI, then the question would be whether your instance actually reads the ssh public key from the meta-data and creates a user with it (like for example cloud-init would do). Amazon is not to blame for what happens in custom images :)

Comment: You're right, I am just starting out, but the image was created by someone who knew what they were doing and I did manage to connect as a result. However that instance was cancelled after the drive wasn't big enough and the tech didnt know how to create an RDS. Ive re used the same image but havent been able to connect due to this private/public key business. Until a domain name starts resolving to an IP there's almost no security risk with using passwords to access the server and its just over-engineering to enforce a no-password-private-key access that isnt even supported natively by PuTTy.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Mark "Until a domain name starts resolving to an IP there's almost no security risk with using passwords" sorry can't agree with that.  Like Martin says, take it to Server Fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can-not login with pem file you have to convert pem file to ppk by using puttygen, then you give your hostname and this newly generated ppk file, it will allow you to login. you have to use ec2-user in user-name.

Comment: as i said you can-not login with .pem file, convert it into .ppk and then try to login. you fill not face any problem .

Answer (score 3):

The default user for the CentOS image is `centos` and NOT `ec2-user`.

Comment: It is correct that the user is `centos`. I was seeing`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).` with `ec2-user`. More info at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to other answers .pem works fine from macOS terminal! It is possible to sign in to CentOS 7.8 on aws using the `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem centos@<public_ip>`.

Converting to ppk just produced an error. All it took was to **change the user** to `centos` as shown below:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key.ppk centos@<public_ip>
Load key "/Users/ilam/.ssh/my_key.ppk": Permission denied
centos@3.87.28.200: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 0):

centos@ec2-**-36-**-160.us-**-2.compute.amazonaws.com and your ppk for auth will get you signed in with putty